# Como contar las veces que pulsa cada item the una lista

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, google-analytics

En mi aplicación, se muestra una lista de coches y pulsando en un coche se accede a una pantalla con la imagen del coche. Este segundo activity recibe un objeto Coche, que de ahí puede conseguir el nombre del coche con getNombre().

Quiero contar las veces que se abre cada coche, para así saber cuales son los coches que mas se visitan. Quiero tener el nombre y una numero, que sería la cantidad de veces que se ha abierto.

He pensado hacerlo así, para guardar los nombres de los coches pero no sé después cuál será el resultado.
¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo?

[image: Mi código, para contar las veces que se abre cada coche]

Comment: Compara tu código con [los ejemplos explicados en la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android). Y, considera siempre poner el código como texto en las preguntas. Para ver los resultados, tienes que entrar en Analytics y allí verás cuando entren a ese método, si tienes todo bien configurado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo ideal sería definir una llave, por ejemplo "auto" y ahí definir el nombre de tu auto  que se obtendrá mediante `coche.getNombre()` :

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("auto", coche.getNombre());
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("autos", params);
```

de esta forma tendrás un parámetro "auto" en donde se registren los nombre de autos y podrás fácilmente realizar una consulta para saber cuales son los coches que mas se visitan.

Comment: @Jorgesys esto estarían bien verdad? 

        FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Nombre_del_coche", coche.getNombre());
        firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Mostrar_coche", bundle);

Comment: Si, el evento "Mostrar_coche" y los nombres autos en "Nombre_del_coche", al registrar los eventos los puedes ver en el Analytics Dashboard